# How do I make Notepad++ show autocomplete when working on .less files?

Tags: autocomplete, less, notepad++

Is there a way to make Notepad++ autocomplete the CSS properties when working with LESS, like it does when working with CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ supports autocomplete via the xml files in its ./plugins/API directory.
[Download](https://github.com/azrafe7/LESS-for-Notepad-plusplus) your LESS.xml or [Here](https://gist.github.com/DanAntFerrari/4452898#file-userdefinelang_less-xml) and add it to the directory, or better follow the instructions in the page.

Comment: When I try to import less.xml from your GitHub link I get a "Failed to import" error.

Comment: try placing the file under C:\users\[username]\appdata\roaming\notepad++
btw, what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on a PC. Putting it in the dir you suggested resulted in the same error.

Comment: I validated the XML file with a validator, it seems all right. You can open any other .xml file and see it it matches with the one you downloaded, if it matches then try putting the file in a differrent drive or something. Or you can use the google.

Comment: Imported this one and this time it worked out. https://gist.github.com/DanAntFerrari/4452898#file-userdefinelang_less-xml. However I don't like the highlighting, it's not the same as it is in CSS. Any ideas?

Comment: you can try adding the css.xml data to the less.xml. I would suggest that you compare the two xm files, the link i gave and the link you used and then mix and match stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64095/discussion-between-argentum47-and-nosille).